# How to define a background image for the page master in Apache FOP 2.0

Tags: background-image, apache-fop

I try to setup a background image for a simple-page-master in FOP 2.0.
I tried the following code:

```
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="Screen169"
        page-height="1080px" page-width="1920px" margin="0" background-image="Screen169.svg"
        background-color="#fecc6c" background-repeat="repeat"
        background-position-horizontal="center" background-position-vertical="center">
```

but is does not work. It does not render the background color neither the background image.
The image should fill the whole page even if the page is not completely covered with text.
What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Background properties [apply to **page regions**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#prapply) and to block-level and inline-level formatting objects, but they don't apply to **page masters**.

Moreover, **their value is not inherited**, so setting them on an element has no effect on its descendants.

Just set them on the `fo:region-body` and you should get the desired result.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: If the background image is full page on you have region-before or after, it will not fill the whole page if you are using region-body for the image. Instead use region-before for the background image and set the extent to the full page height.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use background properties on the master, but you do not need to chop the background up, to fit your individual regions, either.
You simply need to load the background image as an external graphic inside an absolutely positioned container. Place this absolutely positioned container in what ever occupies your top left corner (region-before, region-start, region-body, ...) and it will render beneath everything that follows after it.

E.g. I have a layout with region-before taking the the top 40mm of an A4 page, with region-body and region-after taking up the rest of my page.

Thus:

```
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="mya4">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="region-before">
                <!-- this absolutely positioned container renders
                     a full size background image -->
                <fo:block-container width="210mm" left="0mm" top="0mm"
                    height="297mm" position="absolute">
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:external-graphic 
                            content-height="297mm" 
                            src="/a4-bg.pdf"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
                <!-- all other content must follow after background -->
                <!-- all other region-before stuff goes here-->
            <fo:flow flow-name="body">
                <fo:block>...</fo:block>
            </fo:block>
    </fo:page>
```

renders a4-bg.pdf as a full page background underneath all other page elements.

I use this in a production environment on FOP 2.1, but it should work for older FOP versions as well.

Comment: Tried this. `<fo:static-content>` block needs to be closed. Then I get an error: `The flow-name "region-before" on fo:static-content could not be mapped to a region-name in the layout-master-set.`